# Validation for Add screen not working but it working in edit screen with same code

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-form

I am learning Zend framework and currently I have created add, update , delete functionality for country name and continent name and it is working perfectly.
I have set validation by

```
$name->setRequired('true');
```

and

```
$continent->setRequired('true');
```

in my form.php.

Validation is working in edit form but it return error 'An error occurred' and 'Application error' in add form.
Below is my controller code:

for Add:

```
/*Add Record into Database*/

public function addAction()
{
        $form =new Application_Form_Add();  
        $form->submit->setlabel('Add Country');     
        $this->view->form = $form;          
        if($this->getRequest()->ispost())
        {               
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getpost();             
            if($form->isvalid($formData))
            {
                $file = new Application_Model_Country(); 
                $name = $form->getvalue('name');
                $continent = $form->getvalue('continent');
                $file->addCountry($name, $continent); 
                $this->_helper->redirector('index');
            }
            else
            {                   
                $this->populate($formData);
            }
        }
}
```

for Edit:

```
/*Edit Record into Database*/

public function editAction()
{       
    $form = new  Application_Form_Edit();       
    $form->submit->setlabel('Edit Country');    
    $this->view->form = $form;                  
    if($this->getRequest()->ispost())           
    {           
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getpost(); 
        if($form->isvalid($formData))
        {               
            $id = $form->getvalue('country_id');
            $name = $form->getvalue('name');                
            $continent = $form->getvalue('continent');
            $file = new Application_Model_Country();
            $file->updateCountry($id,$name,$continent);
            $this->_helper->redirector('index');
        }                                      
        else
        {
            $form->populate($formData);
        }      
    }
    else
    {                               
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getparam('country_id');                  
        if($id >0)
        {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getpost();
            $file = new Application_Model_Country();                         
            $files = $file->fetchRow('country_id='.$id);
            $form->populate($files->toArray());
        }
    }    

}
```

Both code are same, then why validation not working in add form?

Comment: Can you please paste the stack trace generated by the error?  It should be in your web server error log.

Comment: i am in at beginning level...so i dont have log or other things...and i have already paste error above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change following code in the `addAction` logic:

instead of:

```
$this->populate($formData);
```

use

```
$form->populate($formData);
```

The reason is `$this` means Action object in this context and you have correctly used `$form` object in EditAction so it is working properly, so it is kind of silly typing mistake.

PS: you should also use proper case in method names like `isPost`, `isValidate` etc. otherwise may get errors in Linux environment.